# Owl Carousel slides appear all as one slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, owl-carousel

i have a problem with owl carousel. i want to have a one slide owl carousel but all my images appear as one slide vertically aligned above each other and not horizontally as the slider direction goes.
below i'll provide u with code and screenshots:

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="projects-slider owl-carousel owl-theme">

    <div class="item"><img src="img/lisi1.jpg" alt="lisi"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="img/lisi2.jpg" alt="lisi"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="img/lisi3.jpg" alt="lisi"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="img/lisi3.jpg" alt="lisi"></div>



    </div>
```

CSS

```
.owl-carousel .item img {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;



}

.owl-carousel .item {
    margin:0px;

}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.projects-slider').owlCarousel({

      navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
      slideSpeed : 300,
      paginationSpeed : 400,
      singleItem:true,
      pagination: true,
      items: 1,


  });

});
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Tasos i have set singleItem to true, 2 lines above if u see. it doesent work even if i remove items:1

Comment: Its not running because you have a coma at the end -- take out (items: 1,) and the last coma here (pagination: true,) so its just (pagination: true) -- you dont need (items: 1) if you have (singleItem:true) -- http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/one.html

Comment: @Tasos no, it doesnt work even without the coma

Comment: then check your browsers console and report back errors. Most probably Owl isnt loaded in properly

Comment: no error in the console :/

Comment: works fine https://jsfiddle.net/q13t0ab8/  -- Add the HEAD of your html page to look

Comment: i added the screenshots in the comments with @Arif, below

Comment: try moving Jquery and Owl Js to the HEAD and leave main.js at the bottom. Something is not executing in time probably the main js file. Do a test -- Let the page load, open the browsers console -- copy and paste the ($('.projects-slider').owlCarousel({  .........) script in the console and hit ENTER to run it  -- does it run?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6qn5x7pd4lxujhx/WEB%20Test%202016.zip?dl=0
heres the whole project

Comment: I checked your project, looks fine as i dont see any problems any were so im not sure why the slides after the 1st one dont appear

Comment: bcz they are stacked all as one slide and it recognizes them as one slide (see my screenshot above how the images/slides are stacked). i think they should be horizontally in line nota vertically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this : [For version 1.3.3 with jQuery 1.9.1]

Change the owl.carousel.js in line 754

```
doTranslate : function (pixels) { 
        var tmp_pixi = 0;
        tmp_pixi = (pixels % 1553);
        return {
            "-webkit-transform": "translate3d(0px, " + tmp_pixi + "px, 0px)",
            "-moz-transform": "translate3d(0px, " + tmp_pixi + "px, 0px)",
            "-o-transform": "translate3d(0px, " + tmp_pixi + "px, 0px)",
            "-ms-transform": "translate3d(0px, " + tmp_pixi + "px, 0px)",
            "transform": "translate3d(0px, " + tmp_pixi + "px,0px)"
            };           
    },
```

**Note :** this `350` will be the height of the image... you can set it static way, or get it using jquery to make it dynamic

Comment: unfortunately this doesnt work neither. heres a screenshot: [link](http://i864.photobucket.com/albums/ab210/batterylove/Screen%20Shot%202016-08-14%20at%2023.56.55.png)

Comment: @IlirBajrami : show me the head section of your index.html file where you loaded all the scripts and css.

Comment: [Head section CSS LINKS ](http://i864.photobucket.com/albums/ab210/batterylove/Screen%20Shot%202016-08-15%20at%2000.10.47.png)
[JS in the bottom] (http://i864.photobucket.com/albums/ab210/batterylove/Screen%20Shot%202016-08-15%20at%2000.10.51.png)

Comment: @IlirBajrami : Check the answer... SOLVED.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120932/discussion-between-arif-and-ilir-bajrami).

Answer (score 0):

You are using an Owl Carousel that is too old with a jQuery that is too new.

Try using a 2.x version of jQuery.

Comment: yes man. i just realised that this owl carousel has two sources for download. i dont know why there are two owl websites. one is so old and one is full of betas and a lot of issues. i just fixed this problem with the newest owl "owl.carousel.2.0.0-beta.2.4" but i had to add a bunch of css to achieve what i wanted to do with the navigation dots. simply so frustrated. anyways i understood how this owl works and now i know what to expect. thanks for showing interest for my problem guys.

Comment: heres the link to the complete plugin with the updated css for the navigation dots:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dpn7436wd6fh1l9/owl.carousel.2.0.0-beta.2.4%20%28Dots%20styling%20fixed%29.zip?dl=0